# Who stole whose hat and coat?

Tags: logical-deduction

After a Halloween party with four guests:

1. All guests took a coat and a hat of another guest (i.e., every one took a coat and a hat but
   not their own).
2. No guest took a coat and a hat from the same person.
3. **A** took the coat of the person whose hat **B** took.
4. **B**’s coat was taken by the same person who took the hat of **A**.
5. **C** took **D**’s hat.

My solution:

> **A** took **B**'s hat and **C**'s coat
>
> **B** took **C**'s hat and **D**'s coat
>
> **C** took **D**'s hat and **A**'s coat
>
> **D** took **A**'s hat and **B**'s coat

Answer (score 3):

Your solution is the ONLY solution because:

> First of all, we know C took D's hat. 
>  
>  Now, let's look at clue 4. C took D's hat, so A couldn't have taken D's coat (because then B would have had to take D's hat, which is impossible because C took it). 
>  
>  Next it's possible to determine D took A's hat and B's coat because A and B can't take their own hat or coat, and C took D's hat. 
>  
>  B had to have taken D's coat, because A can't and C's taken D's hat. 
>  
>  From there, it's possible to deduce the rest easily.

Comment: That's good to hear. I was mainly just checking to see if other people would get the same answer as me :) Thanks!